# After creating a new thread execute the previously created

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Hello I am doing a job to represent a network and we were asked to use sockets and I ended up using threads for communication. I have three classes: Manager, Server and Switch. When the server connects to the manager it creates a thread to receive messages from the manager and send it to the Switch and when the Switch connects to the Server another thread is created to handle the communication between them, that is, the Server will have two threads with different functionalities, one will handle communication between Manager and Server and the other will handle communication between Server and Switch.

But as they are created separately when I accept the switch's connection, the Receive Receiver thread will execute, but the Receive Receiver thread will stop running. How can I run both at the same time? So when the Server receives a call from the Switch it creates the ReceiverSwictes thread but executes the Receiver Manager thread that was previously created and passes parameters to it.

Class Server

```
   public void ligar(int codigoServidor, String nomeServidor, int portaServidor) throws IOException {

    try {

            //connection to the manager
            Socket ligacaoGestor = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 45000);


            //create the input and output channels
            saidaGestor = new PrintStream(ligacaoGestor.getOutputStream());
            entradaGestor = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ligacaoGestor.getInputStream()));
        }

       //sends the data to the manager to add the server to his array
        saidaGestor.println("VerificacaoDadosGestor|" + codigoServidor + "|" + nomeServidor + "|" + portaServidor);

        //thread to receive messages from the manager
         Thread t = new Servidor(entradaGestor, saidaGestor);
         t.start();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Erro de IO: " + ex);
        janelaServidor.receberDados("Comunicação Indisponível!!! Não foi possivel ligar ao Gestor!!!");
    }

//this method is called in the graphical interface and allows sending the data entered by the user to the manager
public void EnviarMsgGestor(String dados) {
    saidaGestor.println(dados);
    System.out.println("ENVIEI MENSAGEM AO GESTOR!!! " + dados);
}

//creates a socket server to receive connections from switches
public void ReceberSwitches(int portaServidor) throws IOException {

    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(portaServidor);

    while (true) {
        //accepts switch connection
        Socket ligacaoSwitch = ss.accept();
           //create the input and output channels
            saidaSwitch = new PrintStream(ligacaoSwitch.getOutputStream());
            entradaSwitch = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ligacaoSwitch.getInputStream()));


        //thread to receive messages from the switches
        ReceberSwitches tt = new ReceberSwitches(entradaGestor, saidaGestor, entradaSwitch, saidaSwitch, array_switches);
        tt.start();
    }
}
```

//run method that receives messages from the manager

```
@Override
public void run() {

    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("WAITING FOR SWITCH MESSAGES!!!!");
            String dados = entradaGestor.readLine();

            if (dados.startsWith("VerificacaoDados")) {
                System.out.println("RECEBI A MENSAGEM!!!!");
                janelaServidor.receberDados(dados);
            }

            if (dados.startsWith("inserido")) {
                System.out.println("RECEBI A MENSAGEM!!!!");
                janelaServidor.receberDados(dados);
            }

            if (dados.startsWith("DadosSwitch")) {
                saidaSwitch.println(dados);
                System.out.println("ENVEI PARA O SWITCH");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Class receive switches(where is the run method to receive messages from the switches)

```
@Override
public void run() {

    while (true) {
        try {


            String dados = entradaSwitch.readLine();

            if (dados.startsWith("DadosSwitch")) {

                String[] s = dados.split("[|]");
                int codigo = Integer.valueOf(s[1]);
                int porta = Integer.valueOf(s[2]);
                Boolean res = false;

                for (int i = 0; i < array_switches.size(); i++) {
                    if (codigo == array_switches.get(i).getCodigo()) {
                        res = true;
                    }
                    if (porta == array_switches.get(i).getPorta()) {
                        res = true;
                    }
                }

                if (res == false) {
                    System.out.println("I WILL SEND SWITCH DATA TO THE MANAGER "+dados);
                    saidaGestor.println("DadosSwitch|"+codigo+"|"+porta);

                } else {
                    saidaSwitch.println("inserido");
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ReceberSwitches.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when the server accepts the connection from the switch goes to the ReceiverSwitches thread and can no longer receive messages from the manager.Because before executing this thread the server is able to receive messages from the manager and send

Anyone who can help me please? Thank you

Comment: *but the Receive Receiver thread will stop running.*  - does not seem to make sense.

Comment: Scary Wombat I think so. I tried to find out or error. If I stop a thread, recipients of switches or servers are already able to receive messages from the manager